# PHPUnit Doctrine error on Controllers CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, phpunit

Using CodeIgniter/CIUnit/PHPUnit/Doctrine combo and having issues running the controllers folder. The models folder works fine, but the controller folder seems to have this error.

```
$ phpunit controllers
PHPUnit 4.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from
 /home/web/web.com/codeigniter/tests/phpunit.xml

.
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader in 
/home/web/web.com/codeigniter/application/libraries/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on line 35
```

Anyone know how to get it to by pass this error. I checked and the only place its being declared is in the ClassLoader.php. Don't see a second redeclaration anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check that you don't include the file twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple change on Doctrine.php

From:

```
require APPPATH.'libraries/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
```

To:

```
require_once APPPATH.'libraries/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
```

Made all the difference.